# Hibernate 2nd level cache not working in read-write startegy

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

Hibernate 2nd level cache implemented using ehcache is not working for "read_write" strategy. Same configuration is working fine for "read_only" strategy.

Observation: Cache is not working when the application is accessed over the network. When I try to access the application from the machine where its deployed and cache data is stored it works fine

Below given is the ecache.xml configuartion

```
<ehcache>
<diskStore path="C:\cache" />
<defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="2000" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="true"/>
<cache name="com.org.ReadData"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="50000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="0" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="true">

</cache>
```

Spring configuration

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer">allow</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ecache.xml</prop> 
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics"> true</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
```

Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: "not working' is way too vague to provide an accurate answer. Please detail the problem better.

Comment: Below given are more detailed steps
1) I have deployed the web application client code (angular2), spring services (interacts with database using hibernate) to tomcat server in machine1
2) Hibernate cache is stored in machine1 and storage location is C:\cache
3) Test the web application in machine1 by using the client url(example:http:\\machine1:8080\app)
4) I measured time taken by rest service by repeatedly performing same functionality using Chrome DevTool (Network)

Comment: 5) Observed 1st time service taking 8 secs and from 2nd time onwards it is taking 2 secs.
6) Now I tried to test the application by opening the client url (http:\\machine1:8080\app) in some other machine. Lets say machine2.
7) This time I observed service is taking 10 to 15 secs always and no time difference.
 
Please let me know for any other clarifications